# How to take a NSString such as, "0+1+2", get the sum of those and create new string. Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, int

Alright. My app has a text field and next to it are two buttons (Plus button and Equals button). When you press the "Plus" button, it takes the text inside of the textField and adds a "+" to it. Code below:

```
- (IBAction)plusButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *plusString = @"+";
    NSString *inputString = carbsField.text;
    NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",inputString,plusString];
    NSLog(@"%@",outputString);
    [carbsField setText:outputString];
}
```

I will eventually make that more intelligent so that I can't put two pluses or whatever. Anyway, then I want the equal button to take whatever is in the textField, which should look something like: "23+54+2.2" and get the sum of those values. I believe I know how to take an Integer and make it a String, but I want to verify it:

```
int value = 56;
NSString *string = @"%d",value;
```

Well, if anyone can show me how to do this, I would be very appreciative. Thanks.

**EDIT**
At the moment, I have not tried anything. This is because I do not know where to start. I have an idea of what to do, but I do not know how to execute it. I believe I need to get all characters before a "+" convert them into `int` and then get the sum of some array of those values.

**Edit #2**
I now use:

```
- (IBAction)equalButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *inputString = carbsField.text;
    NSArray *numbers = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
    int sum = 0;
    for (NSString *number in numbers) {
        sum += [number intValue];
    }
    NSString *theSum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sum];
    NSLog(@"%@",theSum);
}
```

However, it won't log anything at all. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity as I will be working on Objective C soon. Is `int *value = 56` valid? That looks like an invite for UB.

Comment: I am confused on how I got voted down, but perhaps I'll clarify.

Comment: It's not? I thought that is how you create integers in Objective-C. That's what I've been using in my applications and it works fine.

Comment: so you must have quite a lot of warnings in Xcode

Comment: No, that's a number being assigned to a pointer. It's not quite UB but it's definitely not going to behave the way you expect it to. Addition, for instance, will have an implicit `* sizeof(int)` tacked onto the end...

Comment: You are very lucky, if your app didn't crash yet with code like `int *value = 56`. But it certainly didn't do what you wanted.

Comment: Actually, I haven't used exactly that. I have used,
int suffixNumber = arc4random() % 4;
I believe that's in the same form.

Comment: Now you're declaring a variable and not a pointer, that's fine like that.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I was using, int value = 56. That was just a typing mistake, I'll go fix it.

Comment: The `*` makes all the difference...

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys. That exact code wasn't yet implemented, I was just making sure I was right. Which, it turns out, was partly right. The `*` was just a mistake I made in this post. My actual code does not use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how complex this is going to get. If you're looking to implement a more complex calculator I recommend looking for an evaluator library that can do this for you.

However if all you want is to add a bunch of numbers in a list, you could do it like this:

```
NSString *input = @"1+2+3.5";
NSArray *numbers = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
float sum = 0;
for (NSString *number in numbers) {
   sum += [number floatValue];
}
NSLog(@"Result: %f", sum);
```

Note that this is very inflexible code and does only what you described.

Comment: Do you know how to debug in Xcode? Debug your code. I don't see anything obviously wrong right now, but I'm tired. Also, try adding more logs to see where it fails. Log the input string, log the splitted array, log the number in the loop etc.

Comment: ... Okay, biggest fail of my life. I forgot to connect my equalButton with the action. It works great now, thanks a lot. One thing though, it seems to always round my answers. Can I make it stop doing that?

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot guys. I feel quite foolish right now. I'm use to java though, so float is fairly new. I haven't really used it yet. Anyway, thanks to everyone who helped I really appreciate it.

Comment: Pretty much every language has floats. Java does too.

Comment: I am aware of that. But in Java I usually used double or long.

Answer (score 4):

A hint

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"23+54+2.2"];
id result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]; //returns NSNumber object

NSLog(@"%@", result);

if ([result floatValue] ==  [nsnumberWithExpectedResult floatValue]) {
    //WARNING: comparing floats like this is highly dangerous, due to rounding errors 
    // while with ints it is ok
}
```

Comment: neat! i didn't know about NSExpression!